# xlwings - Automation error for simple UDF function setting cell value

Tags: xlwings

I have a fairly basic function that is supposed to set a cell value (in theory a DataFrame, but I've replaced that with 1 as part of my debugging).

```
@xl.func
def RT_GetChartData():
    excel = xl.Book.caller()
    excel.app.display_alerts = False      #I do this because I keep getting OLE errors
    
    excel.sheets("EventDates").range("TempEventOutput").value = 1
    return "done"
```

When I call this function from Excel, it sometimes sets the cell to 1 (but not every time, as I've replaced that with 2, 3, etc and doesn't update), and the cell returns simply

> "Automation error"

Any ideas on whats going on... ?   I've confirmed that the object types are correct, ie Book, Sheet, Range, so I dont think it's that...

Comment: UDFs pretty much only allow you to return values to the calling cell, you can't manipulate the Excel API at the same time. Take out your second to last row and the UDF will return "done".

Comment: Got it - thanks a bunch Felix!  Another unrelated question but hoping you can help.   I have 4-5 UDFs, that are called multiple times, but they all rely on one class instance that only needs to be called once when all the functions fire.   I want to avoid xlwings rebuilding a class instance for each function call every time I calc excel if possible.

Any suggestions on how to do that / articles you can point me to...?  I hope that makes sense. Tx again.